# problems with attachments (javax.mail)

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

i have a problem with the attachments, when I send these files to an email xxx@gmail.com, from the gmail application (mobile application) shows the exact amount of attachments but from Mail (IOS) shows some more.
I apologize for the time !! thank you very much

Note: I am using java-mail.1.4.4

From gmail(native)

[image]

From Mail(IOS)

[image]

Code:

```
 BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
           String htmlText = "HTML code";
             messageBodyPart.setContent(htmlText, "text/html");
             multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            //code for images part ......  //

            //code for attachments
             messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                 String pdf = pdf1;
                 DataSource source = new FileDataSource(pdf);
                 messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
                    messageBodyPart.setFileName(pdf);
                    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

             message.setContent(multipart);                 
                   messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                  String xml = xml1;
                 DataSource sourceXml = new FileDataSource(xml);
                 messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(sourceXml));
                    messageBodyPart.setFileName(xml);
                    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
             message.setContent(multipart);
             Transport.send(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you're using a very old version of JavaMail.  Please [upgrade if possible](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/).

If your html text in your message is referencing the images, you should [create a multipart/related message](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#sendmpr).

If you want that message to also include attachments, you need to nest that multipart/related content in a multipart/mixed, with the multipart/related being the first body part and the attachments being other body parts.

Comment: thanks @Bill. Update the library but it did not work,

Comment: Did you do all the other things I suggested?  If so, and it's still not working, please update your code in your original post.